# Как для visual studio 2015 настроить открытие кода библиотек а не обозревателя обьектов

Tags: c#, visual-studio

У меня установлен `Rechaper` и `visual studio 2015` при `Ctrl + right click` по какому то объекту студия открывает код этого объекта. Но если этот объект системный или находится в другой библиотеке то перейти в него представляется возможным только по `Ctrl+N` и ввести название класса. 
Мне хочется что бы по `Ctrl + right click` я видел не иерархию:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А определение для системных классов и сами классы для подключаемых библиотек.

Comment: А по `F12` не то что вам нужно выводится?

Comment: На `F12` у меня что то другое наверно `Rechaper` назначил и поэтому ничего не происходит.

Comment: Отключите решарпер и проверьте

Comment: Ну мне решапер нужен в любом случае, поэтому если это он переопределил то значит мне нужно понять как переопределить это у него как то, или как в нем переходить в сами классы.

Comment: Я вас прошу не совсем отключить, а лишь на время проверки, там то что вам нужно или нет

Comment: Отключил решепер, на `F12` перешло в обозреватель а не в сам класс.

Comment: Возможно где то можно прописать `Edit.GoToDeclaration` но я не могу найти у решапера хоть каких то настроек кроме выбора 3-х вариантов.

Comment: @Alex Решарпер связан с самой студией, следовательно сами кнопки задаются в самой студии по пути Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard. Можете почитать [тут](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Configuring_Keyboard_Shortcuts.html)